# Approximation of a power series using a do-while loop - C

Tags: c, loops, do-while, numerical-methods, approximation

The title is almost self-explanatory. I was trying to approximate a series that could be written as f(x) = x¹/(1x2) -x³/(3x4) +x^(5)/(5x6) + ... with the condition that the sum should stop when the module of the term is lower than a tolerance inputted by the user. So for example, if x=0.5 and the tolerance=0.01 the result should be 0.239583, because that is the sum of the first two terms (both higher than 0.01). The code below only calculates the first term and then stops the loop for some reason I could not figure out. How to proceed?

```
int main()
{
    double x, e, result=0, term;
    int i=1;

    printf("Write some value to x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    if(x<-1 || x>1)
    {
        printf("Invalid number");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Write the tolerance: ");
        scanf("%lf", &e);

        do
        {
            term=(pow(x, 2*i-1)*pow(-1, i+1))/((2*i-1)*(2*i));
            result+=term;
            i+=1;
        }
        while(abs(term)>=e);

        printf("The result is: %.6lf", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake: "the result should be 0.239583, because that is the sum of the first two terms (both higher than 0.01)".

Comment: .. so please edit the question.

Comment: There's only one way for your `do while` loop to terminate and that is if the absolute value of `term` is greater than or equal to `e` (`abs(term) >= e`). Perhaps `e` or `term` are not what you expect them to be.

Comment: Aside: `abs()` ==> `fabs()` since you are using `double`. Also you must check the `scanf` return value (successful inputs) and then the input range.

Comment: @WeatherVane good catch, `abs` returns int

Comment: Note that you can calcluate all those terms, x^n and (-1)^n, **without** using `pow()`.

Comment: One factor for each step is `-x*x` which you can calculate once and reuse for each new iteration.

Answer (score 3):

[`abs()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_abs.htm) function comes from `stdlib.h` and has signature `int abs(int x)`. Since you are calling it with a float, the number gets truncated. In this case the truncated number is 0, less than the tolerance, so the loop exits early.

You want to use [`fabs()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fabs.htm), a floating point version of `abs()` which comes from `math.h`. It has signature `double fabs(double x)`

Comment: Which would have been caught with `-Wconversion` (which is *not* included in `-Wall` nor `-Wextra`): `test.c:28:19: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion] while(abs(term)>=e);`